# Proof for why symmetric matrices are only orthogonally diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

I am wondering why symmetric matrices are diagonalizable only by orthogonal matrices (and these orthogonal matrices by definition have orthonormal vectors). This is the proof but I don't really get the second part:

[image]

Why is this part true:

> Finally, by Theorem 7.5, you can conclude that P^{-1}AP is diagonal. So, A is orthogonally diagonalizable.

[image]

How do we know it has n linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: Your first sentence is false. It’s not that (real) symmetric matrices are _only_ orthogonally diagonalizable, it’s that you can always find such a diagonalization for them. There are many others—just take your orthonormal basis and multiply each vector by an arbitrary nonzero scalar to get another basis that diagonalizes the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The identity matrix is symmetric, and is diagonalizable by *any* invertible matrix $P$ because $P^{1}IP=I$. So such a diagonalization is not necessarily unique.

If $A$ is symmetric, then it has an orthonormal basis $\{ d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_n \}$ of column eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n \}$. In matrix notation

$$
    A\left[\begin{array}{cccc}| & | & | & | & | \\
          d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & \cdots & d_4 \\
          | & | & | & | & |
          \end{array}\right]
  \\ = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
          | & | & | & | & | \\
          \lambda_1 d_1 & \lambda_2 d_2 & \lambda_3 d_3 & \cdots & \lambda_n d_n \\
       | & | & | & | & |
          \end{array}\right] \\
   =      \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}| & | & | & | & | & \\
     d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & \cdots & d_n \\
       | & | & | & \vdots & |\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
       \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
          0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & \lambda_3 & \cdots  & 0 \\
          \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n
             \end{array}\right]
$$
So $AU=UD$ or $A=UDU^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal. The matrix $U$ is orthogonal because the columns form an orthonormal basis, thereby forcing $U^{T}U=I$.

Conversely, if $A=UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, then every column of $U$ is an eigenvector of $A$ because $AU=UD$.

Answer (score 0):

In the proof of Thm 7.5, the columns vectors $p_i$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.  (You may think about the matrix product on each side of $AP = PD$ in a column-wise manner.)  Since $P^{-1}$ exists at the very beginning of the proof, $P$ is nonsingular.  This forbids the column vectors $p_i$'s from being linearly dependent.  (Otherwise, some column $p_j$ would be a linear combination of other columns, and this would give $\det(P) = 0$, contradicting the invertibility of $P$.)

Answer (score 0):

You constructed $P$ to have columns being orthonormal eigenvectors. You should know a result stating that an set of orthogonal vectors being linearly independent. So the columns of $P$ are your $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.